# Webpack 2 CSS Modules support

Tags: postcss, webpack-2, css-modules, css-loader, react-css-modules

Right now I'm moving my current project from `Webpack 1` to `Webpack 2` and I encounter some problems with css modules which previously worked fine. In particular, I use `css-loader` and `react-css-modules`. My current development configuration is the following:

```
test: /module\.css$/,
use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
           loader: 'css-loader',
           options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'
           }
        },
        'postcss-loader'
   ]
```

It works fine. For production I use `ExtractTextPlugin` (version 2.0.0-beta.4) and my Webpack config for that case goes like this:

```
test: /module\.css$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
          loader: [
                    {
                       loader: 'css-loader',
                       options: {
                           modules: true,
                           importLoaders: 1,
                           localIdentName: '[hash:base64:5]'
                       }
                     },
                     'postcss-loader'
                    ]
                }),
```

In this case build fails with the following error:

```
 Module build failed: Error: composition is only allowed
 when selector is single :local class name
```

So it seems like it doesn't prepend local prefixes. It is also mentioned in the `css-loader` documentation:

> Note: For prerendering with extract-text-webpack-plugin  you should
>   use css-loader/locals instead of  style-loader!css-loader in the
>   prerendering bundle.  It doesn't embed CSS but only exports the
>   identifier mappings.

So I tried loader: 'css-loader/locals' as well as adding it to options, but, unfortunately, nothing works.

I also tried to fix this problem with postcss `postcss-modules` plugin. It fixes the build, but when I try to start my application it looks like it doesn't have appropriate imports of css name mappings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case, that somebody will face the same problem in the future. For this version of ExtractTextPlugin (2.0.0-beta.4) you should set loader parameters in Webpack-1 way. Concretely:

```
 loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
       fallbackLoader: 'style-loader',
       loader: [
           'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[hash:base64:5]',
           'postcss-loader'
       ]
    }),
```

Works fine for me